# question about ODE theory

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

My question is concerning classical solutions given by the Picard Lindelof theorem to
$$\dot{X}(t,x) = f(t, X(t,x))$$
where both $X$ and $f$ belong to $C^1(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n)$. If $(f_n)\subset C(\mathbb{R};C^1(\mathbb{R}^n))$ is a sequence such that $f_n\to f$ in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $f_n \to f$ pointwise in 
$
[0,T]$, how does one prove that
$X_n\to X$ in some suitable norm?

Comment: Then the problem reduces, in my opinion, to: For each fixed $t\in [0,T]$, there is a common Lipschitz constant $L(t)$ for all $f_n$ and $f$. $f$ itself has a global Lipschitz constant $L\le L(t)$. Does the weak convergence along with the continuity properties in $t$  for $\partial_xf_n$ somehow imply that also $L(t)$ is bounded?

Comment: If $L(t)$ is bounded then I'm not sure how weak convergence in $\mathbb{R}$ gives that $X_n\to X$ in for instance $L^1(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^n)$? For instance in the formula $|X_n(t,x)-X(t,x)| \leq \int_0^T |f_n(t,X_n) - f(t,X) |dt$ weak time convergence is insufficient.

Comment: It would be helpful to have an almost trivial example. Let $n=1$, $f(t,x)=x$ and $f_n(t,x)=f(t,x)+h_n(t)$ and $h_n$ is … ? From the counter-examples for $L^1$ convergence and pointwise convergence, $h_n$ could be some hat function, centered around $1/n$ with witdth $1/(2n)$ and height $1$ or $n$. Wikipedias counter-examples for weak convergence include $h_n(t)=\sin(\pi/T·t)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perturbation theory tells us that if $S,T$ are contractive fixed point operators on some convex subset $M$ of a Banach space with 
$$\sup_{x\in M}\|S(x)-T(x)\|=ε$$
then for the iteration sequence starting in the fixed point of $S$, $x_0=x_S$, one gets for the distance to the fixed point $x_T$ of $T$
$$
\|x_T-x_S\|\le\frac1{1-q}\|T(x_S)-x_S\|=\frac1{1-q}\|T(x_S)-S(x_S)\|\le \frac{ε}{1-q}
$$
where $q<1$ is the Lipschitz constant of $T$.

---

Because all of the $f_n$ are in $C^1$, they each individually possesses a global Lipschitz constant in direction $y$ and thus a unique solution by Picard-Lindelöf. Let $L$ be the global Lipschitz constant of $f$. Set
$$
(TX)(t,x)=x+\int_0^t f(s,X(s,x))\,ds
$$
and 
$$
(S_nX)(t,x)=x+\int_0^t f_n(s,X(s,x))\,ds
$$
and use, inspired by a exponentially modified norm commonly used in the Picard-Lindelöf proof, 
$$
\| X\|_L=\int_0^T e^{-2Lt}\sup_{ x}\|X(t,x)\|\,dt.
$$
With this norm, the Picard iteration has contraction constant $q=\frac12$. Then 
\begin{align}
\|TX-S_nX\|_L&=
\int_0^T e^{-2Lt}\sup_{ x}\left\|x+\int_0^tf(s,X(s,x))ds-x-\int_0^tf_n(s,X(s,x))ds\right\|_Ldt
\\
&\le\int_0^T e^{-2Lt}\int_0^t\sup_{x}\|f(s,x)-f_n(s,x)\|\,ds\,dt
\\
&=\iint_{0\le s\le t\le T}…ds\,dt=\int_0^T\int_s^T…dt\,ds
\\
&=\int_0^T\frac{e^{-2Ls}-e^{-2LT}}{2L}\sup_{x}\|f(s,x)-f_n(s,x)\|\,ds
\\
&\le \frac{\|f-f_n\|_L}{2L}
\end{align}
and thus for the difference of the fixed points, which are the solutions of the ODE,
$$
\|X-X_n\|\le\frac{\|f-f_n\|_L}{L}
$$

Now the problem is reduced to showing that 
$$
\| f-f_n\|_L=\int_0^T e^{-2Lt}\sup_{ x}\|f(t,x)-f_n(t,x)\|\,dt.
$$
actually converges to zero.

Note that $\sup_{ x}\|f(t,x)-f_n(t,x)\|$ is still continuous in $t$ and converges pointwise to zero.

A first step is to identify what weak $L^1$ (possibly $L^1\bigl([0,T]\to C^1(\Bbb R^n)\bigr)$?) convergence in $t$ means for a function in $C^1([0,T]\times \Bbb R^n)$.

Comment: I don't understand why $$
\|TX-S_nX\|\le\int_0^T e^{-2Lt}\int_0^t\sup_{x}\|f(s,x)-f_n(s,x)\|\,ds\,dt
\le \frac{\|f-f_n\|_L}{2L}
$$ wouldn't we instead have that $$
 \int_0^T e^{-2Lt}\int_0^t\sup_{x}\|f(s,x)-f_n(s,x)\|\,ds\,dt
=\int_0^t  \|f-f_n\|_L  dt?
$$

Comment: This is essentially one change of the integration order. Note that the integration domain is a triangle. Details now in answer.